# Incrementally print array items using a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, for-loop, google-sheets

I am trying to get one line of the commented out block to repeat at rowEcho depending on batchLength. Replacing the entire function with the commented out 'array' works as expected. This is all happening inside a data:[] object and I am trying to push the values to google sheets to update a cell in each row for as many rows as there are records found in the response array.

Thanks for the replies but neither of those option work as expected. 
I am posting the more complete code to give better scope, as you can see I am using preadsheets.values.batchUpdate request with sheets API to try push the new array however with the batchUpdate method the entire range of new data must be known in order to overwrite, there doesn't seem to be a way to update all cells in a column unless you have the ranges end, hence my below attempt to generate each array with new data for as long as there are rows in the sheet. Dirty I know..

```
function changeSentValue(auth) {   
      var x = 0;
      for (var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {

        // put update spreadt sheet here
        console.log('updating to sent items..');

        const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });

         sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate(request, function(err, response) {
            //var rows = response.data.values;

            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
              return;
            }
    ///here

          });

          var request = {
            spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            resource: {
              valueInputOption: 'RAW',
              includeValuesInResponse: true,
              responseValueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE",

              // The new values to apply to the spreadsheet.
              data: [
                {
                  range: 'Sheet1!A2',
                  majorDimension: "ROWS",
               // values: [[5],[2],[5]]
               values: [

             function getLength ()  {
              var batchRows = response.data.values;
              var batchLength = 13/* batchRows.length */;
              var rowEcho = '[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,\"not\"],'; //col 11
            var y 
              for (y = 0; y < batchLength; y ++) {


                //write(rowEcho);
                 //console.log(rowEcho(y));
                 //these both dont work as expected
                }

                }
                /* [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"notSent"],
                */
              ]


            }
          ],  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

          // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
        },

          auth: auth,
        }


      }


      }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question with more details as the suggestions below answer didn't work in my case.

Comment: It seems that you use the script of Node.js. If it's so, can you update the tags? By the way, where is ``request`` declared? Because when the for loop is run, at first, an error occurs at ``sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate(request, function(err, response) {`` because ``request`` is not declared. How about this? And I cannot understand about ``values: [function getLength() {}]``. If the script is not the latest one, please update it.

Comment: Thank you, yes I declared a request in the code above. Have edited tags. Please refer to the second code block, I updated the original snippet with more code after a better explanation,

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I think that your script is not Google Apps Script, I'm not sure whether you want to use Google Apps Script from your question. I'm sorry. And I cannot understand about ``values: [function getLength() {}]``. If the script is not the latest one, please update it.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getLength() {
var batchLength = 8/* batchRows.length */;
var rowEcho = '[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,\"not\"],'; //col 11
var y
for (y = 0; y < batchLength; y++) {
//You forgot to print it
    console.log(rowEcho);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually printing anything.  Assuming you want this printed in the document body, you'll need to wrap `rowEcho` in a print statement like:

```
function getLength() {
    var batchLength = 8/* batchRows.length */;
    var rowEcho = '[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,\"not\"],'; //col 11
    var y
    for (y = 0; y < batchLength; y++) {
        document.write(rowEcho);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both, I have updated the question with more details as the above answer didn't work, I did try both options before posting :)